# Anyway to define ordered tests using Chutzpah?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, chutzpah

I am using the Chutzpah UnitTest extension in Visual Studio 2013.  The only issue that I am currently having with it is that when I want to run all of the tests, I appears that Chutzpah randomly selects the order in which to run each test.  Is there anyway that I can define the order that I want the tests to be ran?  I know that Visual Studio's native UnitTests are able to do this via the order test files but they don't appear to support JavaScript files.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe if you directly run from the chutzpah.json file it should be using a predictable order. Can you try that?

Comment: When I right click on the JSON file and select the option to run, it says "Total Tests: 0 passed, 0 failed, 0 total".  I am supposed to manually list the tests in the JSON file?  If so how?

Comment: Take a look at the Tests settings documentation https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/tests-setting

Comment: I added the Tests to my JSON file but now my unit tests are no longer able to reference the script in my reference comment tags in my JavaScript files.  Basically all of my tests are now failing because of this.

Comment: Please read this page (https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Breaking-change-to-nested-reference-comments-in-version-4.1). You just need to set ExpandReferenceComments on your tests.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewManela, that resolved the issue with the references not working.  However when I right click on the JSON file and run the tests, they run in the reverse order that they are listed in the file.  I am not so much considered over that as I would like to get the tests to list correctly in the Visual Studio Test Explorer.  They are listing in alphabetical order, which is not what I want.

Comment: Not sure about that one. Is that what test explorer does for C# tests too?

Comment: No but I am able to run by the .NET order test files from test explorer.  Maybe the issue that I am having now is that I would like to see an item appear in the test explorer which is the equivalent of the .NET order tests.